# Swift Concurrency : Why Task is not executed on other background thread

Tags: swift, multithreading, async-await, concurrency, swift5

I am trying to learn the swift concurrency but it brings in a lot of confusion. I understood that a Task {} is an asynchronous unit and will allow us to bridge the async function call from a synchronous context. And it is similar to DispatchQueue.Global() which in turn will execute the block on some arbitrary thread.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        Task {
            do {
                    
                 let data = try await asychronousApiCall()
                 print(data)
                    
                } catch {
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                }
        }
        
        for i in 1...30000 {
            print("Thread \(Thread.current)")
        }
    }
```

my asychronousApiCall function is below

```
func asychronousApiCall() async throws -> Data {
        print("starting with asychronousApiCall")
        print("Thread \(Thread.current)")
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")!
        // Use the async variant of URLSession to fetch data
        // Code might suspend here
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        
        return data
    }
```

When I try this implementation. I always see that "starting with asychronousApiCall" is printed after the `for loop` is done and the thread is MainThread.

like this

```
Thread <_NSMainThread: 0x600000f10500>{number = 1, name = main}
```

Comment: Isn't this because `viewDidLoad` is within a `@MainActor` context, and the task, unless `.detached()` inherits the context it's dispatched in?

Comment: Yes @Shadowrun I think that should be the cause. But this link https://medium.com/@ali-akhtar/swift-new-concurrency-framework-part-1-eac83c17dfb9. Please scroll to figure 8 in last of the article. It has a normal task and Thread is print is some other thread.

Comment: For that: see https://www.raywenderlich.com/books/modern-concurrency-in-swift/v1.0/chapters/2-getting-started-with-async-await Because each await suspend point breaks the task up into "task partials" and at the systems discretion you can be resumed on a different thread

Comment: If I run the same code from Xcode 13 it prints some other background thread. This is interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You said:

> I understood that a `Task {}` is an asynchronous unit and will allow us to bridge the `async` function call from a synchronous context.

Yes.

You continue:

> And it is similar to `DispatchQueue.global()` which in turn will execute the block on some arbitrary thread.

No, if you call it from the main actor, it is more akin to `DispatchQueue.main.async { … }`. As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/init(priority:operation:)-5ltye) says, it “[r]uns the given nonthrowing operation asynchronously as part of a new top-level task on behalf of the *current* actor” [emphasis added]. I.e., if you are currently on the main actor, the task will be run on behalf of the main actor, too.

While it is a probably mistake to dwell on direct GCD-to-concurrency mappings, `Task.detached { … }` is more comparable to `DispatchQueue.global().async { … }`.

You commented:

> Please scroll to [figure 8](https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*PctgST8gtcQYxsQ2VMnT7g.png) in last of [the article](https://medium.com/@ali-akhtar/swift-new-concurrency-framework-part-1-eac83c17dfb9). It has a normal task and Thread is print is some other thread.

[image: figure 8]
figure 8

In that screen snapshot, they are showing that prior to the suspension point (i.e., before the `await`) it was on the main thread (which makes sense, because it is running it on behalf of the same actor). But they are also highlighting that after the suspension point, it was on another thread (which might seem counterintuitive, but it is what can happen after a suspension point). This is very common behavior in Swift concurrency, though it can vary.

FWIW, in your example above, you only examine the thread before the suspension point and not after. The take-home message of figure 8 is that the thread used after the suspension point may not be the same one used before the suspension point.

If you are interested in learning more about some of these implementation details, I might suggest watching WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254/).

---

While it is interesting to look at `Thread.current`, it should be noted that Apple is trying to wean us off of this practice. E.g., in Swift 5.7, if we look at `Thread.current` from an asynchronous context, we get a warning:

> Class property 'current' is unavailable from asynchronous contexts; Thread.current cannot be used from async contexts.; this is an error in Swift 6

The whole idea of Swift concurrency is that we stop thinking in terms of threads and we instead  let Swift concurrency choose the appropriate thread on our behalf (which cleverly avoids costly context switches where it can; sometimes resulting code that runs on threads other than what we might otherwise expect).

Comment: Thank you for such an explanation. It helps to clear a lot about Concurrency. I checked with detached task and made the function nonisolated it appeared to run on another thread. Yes, I am following WWDC Videos.

Comment: There is one more confusion with Tasks as I understood that tasks allows structured concurrency and if I Cancel a Task a subtask will also get canceled but in an example, I tried to cancel the let task1 = Task { await someHeavyTaskFunction }, the task inside someHeavyTaskFunction doesn't get canceled. I checked it with Task.checkCancellation. Please help to make understand this. If it is required to put it in another question, I will create a new question.

Comment: It's hard to say without a specific example, but when a `Task` or `async` function launches another `Task`, that is _unstructured_ concurrency. I.e. this isn't a ”sub-task“, but rather another top-level task on that actor, and you have to manage all the details, such as cancelation, manually. See the discussion about tasks and unstructured concurrency in [The Swift Programming Language: Concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID642). I'd advise only using `Task` and `Task.detached` where you must, and otherwise stay within structured concurrency.

Comment: But, yes, if after researching this, you still have a question, then post a separate question for that.